# JQuery Function Call to Load an HTML file Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load an html file using the jQuery .load function (https://api.jquery.com/load/).

I have created this function in `script.js`:

```
function loadPost(file) {
    console.log(file);
    $("#content").load(file);
};
```

This is what `index.html` looks like:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script>
            loadPost("post1.html"); // does not work
        </script>

        <header>

           // function call works
           <a id="go_home_link" onclick="loadPost('post1.html')" href="#">
               Go home
           </a>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using `loadPost("'post1.html'")`, but that doesn't work either. Any ideas why using the javascript block would not work, but call the function inline in another element does work?

Thanks

Comment: You're using `$("#content")`, but I don't see any HTML element whose `id` is `content` in your code - is this a mistake? If not, then that's probably the reason why.

Comment: Do you see your `console.log(file)` in the console?

Comment: id="content" on which the load function is called but where that id is in HTML. Have a look at it.

Comment: Since the call from the link works, you probably do have the ID in your real HTML. You probably have it *after* the script that calls `loadPost()`, so it's not loaded into the DOM when you call the function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `#content` but, does not exist.

I think you could use an `<iframe>`, something like that:

**index.html**

```
<html>

    <body>

        <header></head>

           // function call works
           <a id="go_home_link" onclick="loadPost('post1.html')" href="#">
               Go home
           </a>
        </header>
        **<iframe id="content"></iframe>** <!-- load page here -->

        <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script>
            loadPost("post1.html"); // does not work
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function loadPost(file) {
    console.log(file);
    $("#content").attr("src", file);
};
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works from `onclick="loadPost('post1.html')"`.

Comment: This won't work unless you put the script after the iframe in the HTML.

Comment: not work, because `#content` not exist in your code and, if you put a div, will produce an error **blocked by CORS policy...**

Comment: You'll only get that error if the URL is in a different domain.

Comment: It's not my code, I didn't write the question. Anyway, you have to put the call to `loadPost()` after the iframe, otherwise `$("#content")` won't find it.

Comment: **"not my code"** rsrs, sorry... About the code, I tested here and working fine...

Comment: You changed the order, now it's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I just discovered my error. First thing, in my question I accidentally removed my the #content div. So there was a div. The mistake I was making was calling the function before the creation of the #content div. So looks like the problem was that I was calling the function on an element that doesn't exist yet